# How to connect European plug to Bosch Siemens plug?

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens, oven, cord-and-plug

I am finally replacing my oven (Siemens) and I noticed that the electricity wiring has a specific Bosch Siemens plug (see image below). My new oven has a "standard" EU wall plug.

[image]

I don't have any way to access the wall sockets directly from the oven area, so now I am left with this problem: how do I connect these two different sockets? I understand the wirings but I do not want to start cutting both ends and connect them manually.

I tried to do some rough search and I couldn't find an adapter between these two connectors. Is there something I could order (or create) that would allow me to nicely plug the EU plug into the Bosch Siemens connector?

I imagine something having a "male Bosch Siemens part" and a female EU plug. Does something like that exist?

EDIT: This exists:

[image]

I am looking for the opposite on both sides.

Comment: Usually different plug designs are for different power outputs, to prevent people from trying to plug into a 5 amp circuit something that needs 20 amps.  Make sure the power rating of that wall outlet matches what the stove/oven needs.  Bosch Siemens does not make their own special design plugs that you need adapters for.  They make plugs that fit into the right outlets.  This is assuming both are from the same region/country.

Comment: Both use 220-240V at 50/60Hz, in terms of power the power coming from the wall is the same, as it has maximum 16A. My goal is to decrease the amount of cutting and manual wiring required. I wouldn't mind removing the EU plug from the new oven and find a way to connect the raw wirings into the Siemens plug but I would prefer finding a neater solution.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that the current connector is the way it is because the previous oven was in fact a Siemens oven. The electrician had to install the Siemens plug to be able to connect the Siemens oven. So, I nothing is different other than the connector used.

Comment: Your images appear to show that the Siemens female connector is on a lead, presumably a lead like your "This exists" lead. What you need to do is remove that lead and plug your new oven into the EU socket. You certainly should be able to access that socket, for precisely this reason.

Comment: Odd.  Usually companies will use their own type of plugs inside of their devices, but connections to house wiring/outlets has to follow standard designs/regulations.

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: @JimStewart Switzerland
#AndrewLeach How do I remove the lead?

Comment: @crip659 yeah, instead we had to have the Siemens plug installed and now it's just there doing nothing (unless we go back to that brand in the future.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach On my setup, there is no such a cable as the  "This exists". The Siemens female lead has been wired up directly into the home raw wirings. That's why the only 2 options are: 1) find a connector for such a lead, 2) cut it and redo the job (or 3) leave it and do a whole new wiring from scratch)

Comment: @N3sh to clarify: what you have attached to your new oven (also are we talking wall oven or range, i.e. cooktop on top of an oven?) is the "2 round prongs" connector on the end of a cord, and your wall has an outlet with a "3 flat prongs" port?  Is the cord attached to the oven in such a way that the wires can be unscrewed inside the oven and the cord detached?

Comment: When codes/standards change as they do over time there comes a point where wiring needs to be redone. I would think that in Switzerland there are regulations. It is time to rewire the house wiring for the oven to meet current standards. Call an electrician or notify building management that this needs to be changed. Are you renting or are you the owner of this property?

Answer (score 4):

The requested adapter doesn't exist.

As far as I know the wall outlet should be reachable, therefor your current situation isn't in order.

The prefered solution should be to make the wall outlet accessible. An illegal solution would be to

- turn power of
- cut the cable
- rewire an new female schuko plug to the cable
- connect everything
- turn the power on and hope that nothing catches fire in the long run.

That is illegal for good reasons:

- An oven consumes a good amount of power for longer durations, therefor high current, therefor needs good conductors.
- Poorly made wiring, or many connections make poor conductors that get hot. (You essentially make two extensions cords)
- All that in a confined room, unsupervised, with dust and dirt is a receipe for disaster.

Nobody would bat an eye if someone would connect an radio with an extension cord, the current is negligible. But an 2.2KW oven is a whole different beast.

Answer (score 2):

Invite an electrician (or skilled handyman) and ask them to move or extend the existing socket that the cable comes from, and install it behind* the oven. Might need to hammer a hole in the wall if there is not enough clearance. Once that is done, simply plug-in the standard plug oven comes with.

It is not recommended to use extension cord and plug it to whatever wall socket is nearby. In fact, the user manual usually forbids any kind of extension cords.

(*) For safety reasons, this socket should be actually on left/right side or even above the oven, so it can be unplugged without pulling the whole appliance out. Do you have a sink next to it? A cabinet that can have its back removed?